# How to pass form field values from associative array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, object, crud

With arrays:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Vova
    [location] => San Diego
)

Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [name] => Rosa
    [location] => La Masa
)
```

used to generate table rows with fetch_assoc:

```
<?php =
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['location'] ?></td>
...and some other fields...
```

Source: https://youtu.be/3xRMUDC74Cw?t=894

How can I do the same while loop without fetch_assoc() to generate div-s and echo field values?

```
bookPost class has in constructor 
{
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->grade = $grade;
    $this->isRead = $isRead;
}
```

Array is created with function getAllBooksPosts():

```
    function getAllBooksPosts(): array
    {

        $lines = file(DATA_FILE_BOOKS);

        $result = [];
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
        [$id, $title, $grade, $isRead] = explode(";",       trim($line));

    $post = new bookPost(urldecode($title), $grade,  $isRead);
    $post->id = $id;
    $result[] = $post;

}
return $result;
```

}

...With function getObjectArray() I create an array:

```
    function getObjectArray() {
        $result = getAllBooksPosts();
        foreach ($result as $v) {
        print_r($v);
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
    bookPost Object
    (
        [title] => Book1
        [grade] => 1
        [isRead] => 1
        [id] => 1
    )
```

...etc

Comment: `foreach ($array as $row)` and the rest is the same.

Comment: ```
<?php
        $array = getObjectArray();
        foreach ($array as $row) {
            echo $row['id'];
        }
        ?>
```
Error:
: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given 
Output: bookPost Object ( [title] => raamat1 [grade] => 1 [isRead] => 1 [id] => 1 )

Comment: Then `getObjectArray()` doesn't return an array like you said it does. Please post a [mre] in the question.

Comment: The error indicates that `getObjectArray()` returns `null`, not an array. Maybe it got an error? You need to check for that before trying to use the result.

Comment: So bookPost is an object, not an array. But I need to iterate it and assign it's constructor values.

Comment: You want `$array = getAllBooksPosts()`, not `$array = getObjectArray()`. `getObjectArray()` doesn't return anything, it just prints the books.

Comment: How do I iterate over the object values and echo them out/assign them to links?

Comment: `foreach ($array as $book)` and then use `$book->title`, `$book->grade`, etc.